# SKSpriteNode positioning

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I am having a really tough time with positioning my sprite nodes on the top of the screen with equal/near equal space between the sprites. The sprites show, but I don't know how to code it in a way that it works on all iDevices(except iPads). Please help :)

```
SKTexture *ure = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"enemy"];
SKSpriteNode *temp = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:ure color:nil size:CGSizeMake(400, ure.size.height)];
CGPoint pos = CGPointMake(70,50);
[temp setPosition: [self convertPointFromView:pos]];
temp.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
[self addChild:temp];


SKTexture *ure2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"enemy"];
SKSpriteNode *temp2 = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:ure color:nil size:CGSizeMake(400, ure2.size.height)];
CGPoint pos2 = CGPointMake(170,50);
[temp2 setPosition: [self convertPointFromView:pos2]];
temp2.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
[self addChild:temp2];


SKTexture *ure3 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"enemy"];
SKSpriteNode *temp3 = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:ure color:nil size:CGSizeMake(400, ure3.size.height)];
CGPoint pos3 = CGPointMake(270,50);
[temp3 setPosition: [self convertPointFromView:pos3]];
temp3.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
[self addChild:temp3];
```

Comment: How do I do this properly, efficiently, and make it work?

Answer (score 1):

```
SKTexture *ure = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"enemy"];
    SKSpriteNode *temp = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:ure color:nil size:CGSizeMake(self.size.width/10, ure.size.height)];//self.size.width/10 for example.
    CGPoint pos = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2 + pos.frame.size.width, self.size.height - pos.frame.size.height);
    [temp setPosition: [self convertPointFromView:pos]];
    temp.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    [self addChild:temp];


    SKTexture *ure2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"enemy"];
    SKSpriteNode *temp2 = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:ure color:nil size:CGSizeMake(self.size.width/10, ure2.size.height)];
    CGPoint pos2 = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height - pos2.frame.size.height);
    [temp2 setPosition: [self convertPointFromView:pos2]];
    temp2.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    [self addChild:temp2];


    SKTexture *ure3 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"enemy"];
    SKSpriteNode *temp3 = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:ure color:nil size:CGSizeMake(self.size.width/10, ure3.size.height)];
    CGPoint pos3 = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2 - pos3.frame.size.width, self.size.height - pos3.frame.size.height);;
    [temp3 setPosition: [self convertPointFromView:pos3]];
    temp3.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    [self addChild:temp3];
```